# You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity. In Data Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to use AlertDialog in RecyclerView but i've got the following problem: **You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.** The same AlertDialog in Activity class works fine but no in DataAdapter.

**styles**

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**manifest**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.simple">
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Data Adapter**

```
private Context mCtx;



    holder.moreOptions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mCtx,holder.moreOptions);
        popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.card_popup_menu);
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()){

                    case R.id.delete_note:



                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mCtx);
                        alertDialog.setTitle("Notice");
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Launching this missile will destroy the entire universe. Is this what you intended to do?");
                        // add the buttons
                        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Launch missile", null);
                        alertDialog.setNeutralButton("Remind me later", null);
                        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                        // create and show the alert dialog
                        AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
                        dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass a theme id too along with Context, like this.
if it helped you, then accept as answer.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_Dialog_MinWidth);
```

Comment: It doesn't worked. I add something like this :AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mCtx,R.style.AppTheme); and now I've got error:   Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Comment: what value you are assigning to context variable?

Comment: This is a part of constructor(Adapter).  public DatabaseListAdapter(Context mCtx, List<NewListModel> newListModels ) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.newListModels = newListModels;
    }

Comment: if you are passing getapplicationcontext() from activity to adapter then replace it with  activity.this and pass it to your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

inside here:

```
switch (item.getItemId()){

                case R.id.delete_note:
                //send message to Handler inside MainActivity:
                android.os.Message message = new Message();
                message.what = MainActivity.SHOW_MY_DIALOG;
                MainActivity.myHandler.sendMessage(message);


                   /* AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mCtx);
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Notice");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Launching this missile will destroy the entire universe. Is this what you intended to do?");
                    // add the buttons
                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Launch missile", null);
                    alertDialog.setNeutralButton("Remind me later", null);
                    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                    // create and show the alert dialog
                    AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
                    dialog.show();
*/

//Now, inside MainActivity, inside onCreate:

myHandler = new Handler(){

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                 super.handleMessage(msg);


  if(msg.what == SHOW_MY_DIALOG)
    CallMethodToShowDialog(); //this method is inside MainActivity
}

//outside of onCreate in MainActivity:

public void CallMethodToShowDialog(){

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this/*mCtx*/); //LOOK HERE!!!!
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Notice");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Launching this missile will destroy the entire universe. Is this what you intended to do?");
                    // add the buttons
                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Launch missile", null);
                    alertDialog.setNeutralButton("Remind me later", null);
                    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                    // create and show the alert dialog
                    AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
                    dialog.show();

}
```